# Instance size of Java object are different in different JVM

Tags: java, object, size, instance

Here I found a problem that instance size of same class are not same in different version of JVM (it's **40** in **1.6.0_21** and **24** in **1.6.0_31**). even though, the code are same.
Do you anyone encounter similar problem before? Or do you have any suggestions?

JDK 1.6.0_21

```
# java -version 
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

# java obj.ObjectSize &

# jps | grep ObjectSize
27251 ObjectSize

# jmap -histo 27251 | grep US_ASCII
 145:             1             40  sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII
```

JDK 1.6.0_31

```
# java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)

# java obj.ObjectSize &

# jps | grep ObjectSize
26645 ObjectSize

# jmap -histo 26645 | grep US_ASCII
161:             1             24  sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII
```

ObjectSize.java

```
package obj;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import sun.nio.cs.US_ASCII;

public class ObjectSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        US_ASCII as = new US_ASCII();
        System.out.println(as);

        try {
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this a problem for you?

Comment: If I use jre 1.6.0_21, the total memory usage will be larger than that using 1.6.0_31.

Comment: So don't use 1.6.0_21.  After all it is VERY out of date.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are encountering is just a fact originating in how compiled programming languages work, especially if they run inside a VM.

Changes in the implementation of the virtual machines are allowed to behave differently, e.g. producing Java byte code of different sizes -- *as long as they keep to the same Java API*.

Is the difference in memory usages really that big? If the increase in memory size is actually a problem I would dare to suggest that you already had a memory problem in the first place.

If you were working at 50% capacity with one VM and are now hitting the cap with the other I guess you need to undertake some deeper changes in your code. Or throw more hardware at the problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Early versions of Java 6 supported `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` but it was off by default. (The first versions of Java 6 didn't support this at all)  This means that references in a 64-bit JVM were 64-bit.  In newer JVMs, a 32-bit reference is used if the heap is < 32 GB. It can do this as obejcts are 8-byte aligned so you can address 2^32 * 8 bytes with a 32-bit reference.

Note: US_ASCII inherits three fields from Charset

```
private final String name;          // tickles a bug in oldjavac
private final String[] aliases;     // tickles a bug in oldjavac
private Set<String> aliasSet = null;
```

These references are 4-bytes smaller saving 12 bytes, however objects are 8 byte aligned so the total saving is 16 bytes.

Using compressed oops reduces the amount of memory used.

[Compressed oops in the Hotspot JVM](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops)

BTW: You wouldn't use this class directly, instead you would use `StandardCharset.US_ASCII`

Comment: [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) was added in Java 7, so it isn't available when you use Java 6

Comment: If you can't use StandardCharsets, you can use `Charset.forName("US-ASCII")` which is what this class does in reality.

Comment: Thanks Peter Lawrey, I also find below link that talking about **-XX:+UseCompressedOops**. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any suggestions?

If the usage of memory is that important to you, don't use the 64-bit version of 1.6.0_21.  Switch to the 32-bit version, or a more recent patch level.  Or better yet, Java 7.  After all 1.6.0_21 is VERY out of date.

Alternatively, run the JVM with the option to explicitly enable compressed oops as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html):

> *"For JDK 6 before the 6u23 release, use the -XX:+UseCompressedOops flag with the java command to enable the feature."*

(But beware that this might tickle bugs in what was ... at that time ... still an experimental JVM feature.)